# Best practice to use string data from a file

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

What is the best practice to create a text-based database for a PowerShell script?

What I really mean exactly?
I have a PowerShell script which use an url. This address may be used in other PS scripts, but I would be pretty happy if a quite simple practice is exists to solve to store this URL (or more) in a file, and the scripts use form this content, what I only have to define, which variable, line should be used, like this:

```
SharePointUrl = "..."
CcUrl = "..."
```

And in the script:

```bsh
$SPUrl = DataFile.SharePointUrl ...
```

Something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly. Are you looking for something like this?

```bsh
$SharePointUrl = 'http://www.example.org/...'
New-Object -Type PSObject -Property @{'URL'=$SharePointUrl} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\some.csv' -NoType
```

---

```bsh
$DataFile = Import-Csv 'C:\path\to\some.csv'
$SPUrl    = $DataFile.URL
```

---

**Edit:** After re-reading your question it seems you have an input file with `key=value` pairs. That can be processed like this:

```bsh
$DataFile = Get-Content 'C:\path\to\data.txt' -Raw | ConvertFrom-StringData
$SPUrl    = $DataFile.SharePointUrl
```

Another option is to write the configuration to a second PowerShell script:

```bsh
# as variables
$SharePointUrl = "..."
$CcUrl         = "..."

# or as a hashtable
$DataFile = @{
    SharePointUrl = "..."
    CcUrl         = "..."
}
```

and [dot-source](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847841.aspx) that script in your original script.

```bsh
. 'C:\path\to\config.ps1'
```

Comment: Yes, exactly, I think it's pretty fits to my idea as well..., thank you!

Comment: Yup, my original concept was, I have an existing data file, so your second solution a bit better, perfeclty works..., so thanks!